# Visual Studio 2015 migrate database from SQL Server 2012 LocalDB - error on login

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015

I just started working with the new Visual Studio 2015. My existing web application seems incompatible on the database version as shown in the image below [image]

I did install SQL Server 2012 yet the alert keeps appearing. And the project database does not work. When I try to register a new user account on the application, it tries to load the page for a long time and finally shows this error message:

> Win32Exception (0x80004005): the system cannot find the specific file
>
> Línea 158:                    company = model.Company
>   Línea 159:                };
>   Línea 160:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
>   Línea 161:                if (result.Succeeded)
>   Línea 162:                {

The error occurs at line 160.

Any ideas how to get it correctly configured?

Thanks

Comment: If you installed the database indicated by the error message, but are still seeing the message while throwing a Win32 Exception, I wonder if perchance you've installed a 64-bit version of SQL Server Express while your application, somehow, has taken a hard dependency on the 32-bit version...? A stretch, to be sure, but...

Comment: actually the link on the message directs to the sql server 2014 version but I searched and installed 2012 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem the solution was to download Sql server 2012 local db 
You can find it here :
[64 bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x64/SqlLocalDB.MSI) or [32 bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x86/SqlLocaLDB.MSI)

Comment: wonderful, it seems I installed the wrong package of sql server 2012 which did not include local db. I found the downloads page slightly confusing...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but in my case, I wasn't concerned with backwards compatibility.  I wanted to upgrade the database and not install any older SQL tools.  It took me a while to figure it out because the steps Visual Studio suggests and the Microsoft help link VS provides didn't work.

The trick is to add the existing LocalDB file as a New Connection.

1. Under Server Explorer, right-click Data Connections, and choose "Add Connection..."
2. Point to your existing file.  Use the default "Use Windows Authentication."  Don't bother trying to "Test Connection" because that will give you the same error.
3. Choose OK, and a new pop-up will finally ask you if you want to upgrade the database.
4. Choose yes, and instead of creating a new connection, it will upgrade the database and you will be able to use your existing Connection.